# self keyword after wildcard import

Tags: rust

Let's say I have the following `main.rs` and `lib.rs` files. Why after doing the wildcard import `self` refers to `testing::nested` and not the `main` binary module anymore?

Could somebody point me to documentation where they explain this? I haven't been able to find it.

```rust
// main.rs
use testing::nested::*;

fn main() {
    self::hello();
}

// lib.rs (testing module)
pub mod nested {
    pub hello() {
        println!("hello from nested::hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what `use` does. It brings names into scope as if they were defined in the current module.

Comment: Just to elaborate on @IvanC's comment, `self` still refers to `main` (it's unchanged) but `main` now contains the imported symbols: in this case the `hello` function.

Comment: Ohh of course, I don't know how I missed that, lol. Thank you folks!

Answer (score 1):

Just like @Ivan and @eggyal mentioned, is not that `self` refers to `nested`, is that the `use` declaration created a binding for `hello` in the `main` module.